# Does "each creature in blast" include allies?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat, powers

When a power says "Each creature in the blast", does that mean my allies are hit by the attack too? I play a Control Wizard/Witch and almost all of my powers are blast and burst that target creatures.

Comment: Sure - real military ordinance does this too. It's called "friendly fire"

Comment: @DaleM: Friendly fire... isn't. ;-)

Answer (score 15):

Yep, allies are hit too, otherwise it would say "each Enemy in the blast", as is the case on plenty of attacks (For example, [Fire Shroud](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/Fire_Shroud), contrast with [Shock sphere](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/Shock_sphere)).

Answer (score 12):

**Yes, it means enemies and allies**

> **Creature**
>
> A being in the game world. Both adventurers and monsters are creatures. See also adventurer and monster. - Published in Rules Compendium, page(s) 310.

**There are options for avoiding friendly fire while still laying down a burst/blast zone that includes friendlies**

War Wizard's Staff feat lets you slide an ally out of the way before the attack goes off (if you are wielding an arcane implement). War Wizard Expertise applies a -5 to-hit modifier for burst and blast powers cast through a light or heavy blade against allies.